# NSScrollView and lion .. is it possible to only show scrollbars when scrolling

Tags: cocoa, osx-lion, nsscrollview, nsscroller

Is it possible to have an NSScrollView ignore the system preferences setting and only show scrollers when scrolling.  My application is designed for the overlay style scrollers only unfortunately, so I want to avoid having to adjust the containing content views.

Is this possible?

Comment: It sounds like your application is designed wrong, then. It's generally considered a very bad idea to ignore user preferences and do something else. Can you describe why you did this?

Comment: You'll have to ask the designer...  :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would take a look at `NSScroller`'s [setScrollerStyle:](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSScroller_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSScroller/setScrollerStyle%3a).  That should do the job.

However, I'd like to share that I personally think forcing users into using one style of scrollers over the other is indicative of *bad design*.  The system allows users to choose and I believe apps should honor that choice. The fact that your content view doesn't handle horizontal nor vertical resizing is a big red flag and I would revisit that design choice.

Good luck.

Comment: Believe me..  I completely agree. It's not a typical view. Thanks for the direction!

Comment: Whoops.  Important typo!  Thanks @Peter!